# Sum an array as integers are added to an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I sum an array as items are added to the array. I have a dynamic table which allows users to select the number of rows in the table. Each row has a input for a 1 to 10 number. Each input is added to an array with the following function

```
$scope.redRoundScore = [];

$scope.updateRedScore = function(passedscore, index){
  $scope.redRoundScore[index] = passedscore
}
```

And the HTML

```
<input required="" ng-change="updateRedScore(inputValueRed, $index)" ng-model="inputValueRed" type="number" step="1" name="rate" min="1" max="10">
```

I have tried changing the function to this but it does not seem to be working.

```
$scope.updateRedScore = function(passedscore, index){
  $scope.redRoundScore[index] = passedscore
  $scope.redScoreSum = redRoundScore.reduce((p,c) => p + c);
}
```

I want to have the sum dynamically calculated as users enter a number for each row, and have the sum bound to another cell at the bottom of the table.

Comment: Probably you missed `$scope` in reduce? `$scope.redScoreSum = $scope.redRoundScore.reduce((p,c) => p + c);`

Comment: That definitely was a mistake, but it still is not working after correcting that.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: "redRoundScore is not defined"

Comment: It is defined above the same function though, and it works for adding to that array.

Comment: Do you understand that `redRoundScore` and `$scope.redRoundScore` are NOT the same thing? What is the difference?

Comment: I do understand. That console log made me realized though that Chrome was caching my older .js file and did not take the $scope.redRoundScore.reduce((p,c) => p + c); fix you suggested. I force refreshed and disabled cache and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Happy to help!